# regex replace occurrence of two character with one.

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to implement a regular expression that will replace the occurrence of two or more characters with one. but I didn't know to do this.

this is my string

```
   example--of---string.
```

I need a regular expression that will give me output like this

```
  example-of-string.
```

Is this is possible in regular expression, preg_replace in php.

or I need to access the elements though array and check for next character and skip if it is -

Please advise me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = 'example--of---string.';
$new_string = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
echo $new_string;
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Regular Expression

```
(.)\1+
```

This will pick up any occurrence of the same character repeated more than twice. Not just dashes.

#### Replacement String

```
\1
```

#### Online demo

http://regex101.com/r/rF3bK5

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
/-{1,}/g
```

Replace with:

```
-
```

Demo:<kbd>http://regex101.com/r/uV1qZ7</kbd>

Comment: This is not the most optimal pattern syntax.